# Problems using std::queue() in Unix

Tags: c++, unix, c++11, std

I have the following code in my program:

```
std::queue<typename Leftist_node<Type> *> traversal;
```

It compiles and work fine when I run it on Windows. However, when I run the exact same program on Unix, I get the following error:

```
Leftist_heap.h:89: error: template argument 1 is invalid
Leftist_heap.h:89: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

I also get these messages when trying to work with the queue:

```
Leftist_heap.h:92: error: request for member âpushâ in âtraversalâ, which is of non-class type âintâ
```

Is there any reason for this? Do I need to change something to make it work on Unix?

Comment: You should write also where and how is `Leftist_node` defined or, even better, come up with a small but self-contained code snippet which replicates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

remove the **typename**.
`std::queue<Leftist_node<Type>*> traversal;`

**typename** tell compiler tokens behind are types, not variables. in your example, `Leftist_node<Type>*` is a exact type. so you don't need keyword typename.

```
#include <queue>

template<typename T>
class Leftist_node{};

class Type{};

template<typename T>
typename T::value_type front(T& queue)
{
  typename T::value_type v = queue.front();
  return v;
}

int main()
{
  std::queue<Leftist_node<Type>*> traversal;

  std::queue<int> q;
  q.push(1);

  return front(q);
}
```

gcc version 4.8.2 and clang version 3.5.0.